# Node.js double pipe "finish"/"close" emitted when?

Tags: node.js

Say I have

```
var p = a.pipe(b).pipe(c);
```

If I have

```
 p.on("close");
```

somewhere else, would it run when a finishes piping into b, or when ab finishes piping into c?

Answer (score 0):

stream.pipe will return Writable stream (not every writable stream will emit "close" event).

Use:

```
p.on("finish", ...)
```

**Answering your question** - finish will be emited by **c**